# https can not establish a private connection

Tags: https, certificate

guys, I need your help. Here is the problem I face now:

I have a Dell XPS laptop and install windows 10 and Linux Mint 18 on it. To keep the clock consistent with my time zone, I have used the following command in Linux:

timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock

The problem now is, in windows 10, I can only connect to Gooogle or gmail during the beginning of the reboot. After long time, or after a suspension of windows 10, I can not connect to Google service anymore. It will report "can not estabish private connection". I can connect to other website normally. The same problem also exist for my dropbox. It will report "can not establish a secured connection".

I have checked the certificate of https for Google services, it seems that the browser locates to a wrong certificate when the connection is failed.

The problem disappear if I use a VPN connection.

I guess the problem is related to clock setting in my windows system, but I don't know how to solve it.

any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem is that I use manual DNS settings, so the time in my computer and the server is not consistent. Just need to convert to auto DNS.

Sorry for the interrupt.